# Converting PNG image file into row of pixels for saving in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, image-processing

I am working on an image dataset for classification. I want to store all the pixel values of the image in a single row in the pandas dataframe.
I am able to convert the image into a matrix and then into an array but when I'm saving this array, it is getting saved in the columns.

I used

```
img = mpimg.imread(path_for_png)  #for getting image data into matrix 
img = np.ravel(img)    #this method for converting it into an array
```

And now when I apply this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(img)   #to convert it into dataframe
```

I get the dataframe in the format shown below but I want to convert it into a single row for a single example.

```
    0
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame` on a list images to put each image on a separate row. Since there is only one image here, adding `[]` is enough depending on the output you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([img])
```

will give

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

while

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[img]])
```

gives

```
    0
0   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

The second output is most probably what you want if the array is long.

Comment: Can you explain me why we are doing like this

Comment: @SuperUser_15: Since `img` is jsut an array of numbers by using `pd.DataFrame(img)` it will by default be a single column. Using `[img]` instead means that your values are now in the first position of a two dim array and it will become a row in the dataframe. You could try adding more arrays and see that more rows are added. Finally, the last one is a three dim array and will put all values in the (0,0) position of the dataframe.